# Use one AngularJS code from different pages

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to call one AngularJS code(function) from different pages? I've found 2 ways, but they aren't solve the problem.

First way is to use a `$rootScope`. Then logic of my function will be placed into `$rootScope`.

```
var sharedFunctions=angular.module('shared',['$rootScope']);

sharedFunctions.run(
    function($rootScope){
       $rootScope.translate=function(language, text){
               for (var i = 0; i < text.translatedTexts.length; i++) {
                   if (text.translatedTexts[i].language == language) {
                       return text.translatedTexts[i];
                   }
               }           
       };
    }
);
```

But I'll still have to create a function inside my controller, that call `$rootScope` fuction.

```
$scope.translate=function(language,text){
    $rootScope.translate(language,text);
}
```

Second way is simular to first way, but difference is logic part of my function will be placed in `service` or `factory`.

Reason, why I won't take these solutions: I'll have to write code(just a few lines, that call main logic) in each controller.

Comment: I usually only use Angular for building Single Page Applications; so when you say 'different pages' do you mean different views?  Or different controllers?  Normally I would put shared functions into a service.  If you need to access it in a view; you can put the full service into the $scope, or just the function

Comment: First: if it's in the root scope, then it's accessible to all the views, since all scopes inherit from the root scope. If the goal is to have a function accessible from the view, why don't you make it a filter or a directive?

Comment: @JBNizet, my attempt to access `$rootScope.translate` from the view didn't give me any results(`ng-bind="translate(language,text)`).  Or it's necessarily, to create filter or directive? I.e. call `$rootScope` functions from them?

Comment: @JeffryHouser, I mean different views. Each my view have only one controller.

Comment: That's probably because you're using `$rootScope.translate()` instead of just `translate()`. Every expression in the view is always, implicitly, evaluated on the scope, which inherits from the root scope. So using `$rootScope.translate() `actually calls `$scope.$rootScope.translate()`.

Comment: @JbNizet, no, i write just `translate()` in my view. Thanks anyway, now I'm convinced , that it's possible to call `$rootScope` function from the view, because `$scope` inherits all functions from `$rootScope`.

Comment: You're doing something wrong, but wthout your real code, we can't say. Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZMUWvl8ccLWRgQodZO39?p=preview

Comment: @JBNizet, thank you! My problem occures because of funcions if `$rootScope` was written in other module.

Comment: Putting stuff in `$rootScope` is like the smaller brother of the most evil thing in JS - polluting the global scope. If you need some custom translation logic - probably your best bet would be a directive.Otherwise check [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate).

Comment: @boyomarinov, but what if I need some function that will be used at every of my views? Why it's a bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i've discoveret how to share code between the views.

Step 1: create root module and configure basic functionality.

```
'use strict';
var app=angular.module('rootApp',['ngRoute','appFactories']);

app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.translate = function (language, text) {}
    //other functions
});

app.filter('filterName', function() {
   .....
});
//other filters
```

Step 2: create submodule for my view and add root module as dependency

```
'use strict';
var cardEditApp=angular.module('submoduleApp',['ngFileUpload','rootApp']);
```

Step 3: in my view use `ng-module="submoduleApp"` with name of my submodule. Then I'll can use functionality of the controller of my submodule and functionality of root module.